# Can't get information about DynamoDB backups using AWS Golang SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I need to get information about DynamoDB tables backups.
So lets say I have backups listed in dashboard:
[image]

I can't get any backups using Golang SDK though:

```golang
import (
...
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
...
)
...
svc := dynamodb.New(c.providerConfig.Session, regionConfig)
response, err := svc.ListBackupsWithContext(ctx, input)
// response.BackupSummaries is empty

backupArn := <ARN of any of the backups from dashboard>
output, _ := svc.DescribeBackupWithContext(ctx, &dynamodb.DescribeBackupInput{BackupArn: &backupArn})
// even with requesting for a backup by specific ARN we have no luck
// output.BackupDescription is nil
```

Other functions (1. getting tables with `ListTablesPagesWithContext` 2. getting continuous backup description with `DescribeContinuousBackups`) works perfectly. The only thing i can't get (non-continuous) backups.

Can someone help with explanation why I keep getting empty responses though DynamoDB table backups listed in dashboard?

Answer (score 3):

The default settings for [`ListBackups`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListBackups.html) is `BackupType:USER`. This means when you call ListBackups you are only being returned ones that are manually created. As your backups are maintained by AWS Backup, you should set the `BackupType` parameter to either `ALL` or `SYSTEM`.

Hope that helps.

Note I attempted to fix your code, but Go is not my strong point (50% chance of being correct :) )

```
backupArn := <ARN of any of the backups from dashboard>
backupType:= 'ALL'
output, _ := svc.DescribeBackupWithContext(ctx, &dynamodb.DescribeBackupInput{BackupArn: &backupArn, BackupType: &backupType})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my issue. Still getting empty response, even after setting `BackupType` to `ALL`. Also, most of my backups are created by hand

Comment: So you are being returned no backups at all? What do you get in the response?

Comment: I have the same problem, I get an empty response from the ListBackupsCommand call. I created 3 backups for a dynamo table from AWS Backup service and 1 backup for such table from the Dynamo service, so, this one is only returned in the response, the others not. This my call:
await client.send(
        new ListBackupsCommand({
            TableName: table.TableName,
            BackupType: 'ALL',
        }),
    );

Comment: I just saw in the AWS documentation that it's only possible to get the AWS backups from the other side.

"If you want to retrieve the complete list of backups made with Amazon Web Services Backup, use the Amazon Web Services Backup list API."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/dynamodb/command/ListBackupsCommand/